# Append Iframe src

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function where onclick, I want the iframe to append to another div within my website. So when the user clicks 'watch-youtube-video', this will then grab the iframe from 'youtube-video' and append just the src to the 'fixed-player' iframe src.

I have tried using the below jQuery but I am hitting an error. Could anyone please help?

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-player"><iframe src=""></div>

<div class="span-row wow scale-anm all animated">

    <div class="portal-img ">

        <div class="youtube-video">
            <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://youtube.com/embed/10zsTgv8MxA?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;loop=1" allowautoplay="" allowfullscreen="" data-origwidth="100%" data-origheight="100%" style="width: 0px;">
            </iframe>
        </div>           


    </div>

<div class="portal-cont ">

  <div class="top-cont ">

    <div class="main-button grey-btn watch-youtube-video">
      Watch Video
    </div>           

  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.watch-youtube-video').on('click', function(){
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    $('.youtube-viewer-pop').fadeIn();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("iframe").attr("src").appendTo('fixed-player');
});
```

Comment: What's the error?  We can't help with the error if you don't tell us what the error is :)

Comment: Oops! Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...).parent(...).parent(...).find(...).attr(...).appendTo is not a function

Comment: It's because `attr('src')` returns a string. You can't call `appendTo()` on a string.

Answer (score 0):

To set the `src` attribute of a jQuery object, you should be using the [`.attr()` method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead, i.e.: `.attr('src', <SOURCE>`) instead:

```
const src =  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("iframe")[0].src;
$('.fixed-player').attr('src', src);
```